# How i work with mongodb in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

How i use mongodb in ruby on rails, how i run rake command?
What i do step by step?
Please tell me with scaffold example.
I'm beginners in ROR.
.............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: What's with all the ...?

Comment: this post is not add so i type this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Mongoid](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/index.html)
But if you are a beginner, I recommend you to start studying ruby before jump into rails

Comment: what i do first for mongoid?

Comment: See the `Installation` link on Mongoid's website

Comment: If my answer was helpful, you should 'accept', that way another users can benefit from your question

Comment: but your answer is not fulfill my requirement.

Comment: "Could not find generator mongoid:config."  please help me give this error after run this command "rails g mongoid:config"

Comment: You should make a new question